# Heroku Postgres - The server does not support SSL connections

Tags: postgresql, ssl, heroku, connection, heroku-postgres

I have been working on an small app and connecting with Heroku PostgreSQL, for many days was working right but now is showing me this SSL error

`The server does not support SSL connections`

I have been looking for solutions but I cannot find anything that works for me, my code is:

```
import pg from 'pg'
import db from '../config.js'

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  host: db.host,
  database: db.database,
  user: db.user,
  port: db.port,
  password: db.password,
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
})
export default function query(text, params) {
  return pool.query(text, params)
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the full traceback.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it from Pool to Client and then using that to connect and query.

```js
async function get(){
  const client = new pg.Client({
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    user: ...,
    password: ...,
    port: ...,
    host: ...,
    database: ...

  });
  
  client.connect();

  const response = await client.query(`SELECT * FROM ...;`)

  return response.rows
}
```

Double check your values in the Heroku database.

Also, in production, you should just need

```js
const client = new pg.Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
}
```

The first set of code is for local connection to your db.

One last note, I would put your user, password, etc... into a .env file and don't commit that to your repo.

UPDATE:

You can also put this into a config file like `./db.config.js` as the following

```js
const pg = require('pg')

module.exports = 
  process.env.DATABASE_URL 
  ? 
    new pg.Client({
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
    })
  :
    new pg.Client({
      // connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      database: process.env.DATABASE
    })
```

So if it is in production, it will use the database url, and if there is none (which is local) then it will use the username password connection.